# Hibernate use openConnection inside Transaction and use getCurrentSession outside of Transaction

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions, connection, database-connection

I am learning Hibernate recently, it gives me a lot of headache, as I have been using `DataSource.getConnection` all the while in my application, learning `Session` concept in Hibernate is quite difficult. I can't really find enough information or confirmed information from the API/Doc too.

I have read through [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html). I understand if I have a container managed transaction (I am using `HibernateTransactionManager` and mostly with Spring's `Transactional` annotation), most of time, I supposed to use `getCurrentConnection` (inside transaction), as in it will return me the only connection bound to the transaction context.

But sometime I have to use some other people method/code/library/framework that possibly inside will be using `openConnection` (I am not able to change their code), I would like to know, what is the consequence of doing this? Will the connection obtained in this way is the same session as `getCurrentConnection` (since it is called inside transaction)?  Or it is different? If it is different, will it bind to transaction and managed by the transaction too? While I say "managed by" meaning, transaction context will set it as `auto-commit false` and upon `Transaction.commit`, transaction will help to commit the changes (might as well for rollback too)?

It extends my thought, what if I called `getCurrentConnection` outside of the Transaction? There is no transaction context, so what is the connection being returned? and where the connection bound to? Based on this [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html), I can see doing like this is valid, but it doesn't explain what is the consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But sometime I have to use some other people
>   method/code/library/framework that possibly inside will be using
>   `openConnection` (I am not able to change their code), I would like to
>   know, what is the consequence of doing this?

Ok I have tested the code as above, it will create a new hibernate session, which mean, I have to manually handle the session, include close it and flush it.

> It extends my thought, what if I called getCurrentConnection outside
>   of the Transaction?

This will totally no working, it will throw exception because it can't find any active transaction outside the transaction block.